# Storing training dataset in a platform like mlflow

Tags: machine-learning, training-datasets, storage

I am pretty new to Machine learning and would like to know whether there are **experiment management platforms** that also allow **storing** and managing training datasets (images, in my case). I am familiar with the ML-Flow, but IMHO it doesn't support such an option, am I right? Anyways if there are any, please tell me which. If there are no platforms like this, how would you suggest managing training datasets in combination with existing platforms? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a DVC (Data version control) tool. One such tool is available at [dvc.org](https://dvc.org/)

[image: What is DVC]

You can go through their documentation to get started.

https://dvc.org/doc/start